# how to prevent telegram bot keyboard from scrolling

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am writing a telegram bot with [telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf).
I have a keyboard like this:

```
.keyboard([
      [L.__('Start Order'), L.__('Game')],
      [L.__('Promotions'), L.__('Search')],
      [L.__('Invite Friends'), L.__('Download Apps')],
      [L.__('My Scores'), L.__('My Orders')],
      [L.__('Ostadkar Telegram Channel'), L.__('FAQ')],
      [L.__('Work at Ostadkar'), L.__('About Ostadkar')],
    ])
    .oneTime()
    .resize()
    .extra()
```

But the number of commands on it are much more than the space it has and needs scrolling to view all of it.
How can I fit this keyboard to screen without scrolling it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think that there is such a capability in telegram bot.

Comment: I think you might find the solution now in here: https://www.codeease.net/programming/javascript/telegraf-js-keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible at this time and according to telegram bot guidelines and news, its not even in the to do list.